# Widget-removed-event available?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.5

I have a panel that makes use of a simple vertical layout. From time to time some of the widgets in this panel are removed. What I want to do in such a case:

- remove one of the separators that is placed between every of these widgets
- rearrange the layout to avoid large gaps where the widget and separator have been removed

The problem is, such a widget deletes itself automatically, the parent panel not necessarily knows about this operation. Therefore my question:

Is there some kind of "child-widget-removed"-event available which can be received by the parent and can be used to start the procedure of re-layouting the panels contents as described above?

Thanks!

Comment: If "widget removed" is the same as "widget deleted" you can use `QObject::destroyed()` signal of that widget to be notified when it is about do gone.

Comment: @vahancho: this is not exactly what I'm looking for, I'd need a possibility where the PARENT is notified, not the widget itself

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem? You can connect `destroyed()` signal of the child widget to the parent's slot. Parent will be notified as soon as a child is destroying.